Calcular porcentaje (probabilidad) de un valor
Estoy intentando calcular un porcentaje basado en un numero total de partidos jugados por parte de un equipo y su respectivo resultado (ganado, perdido, empatado) para calcular una probabilidad  muy simple.
La única tabla que dispongo ya contiene todos los datos directamente (equipos, resultados y fecha):
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID  | TIME                | HOME                    | VISIT                   | RESULT_HOME | RESULT_VISIT |
+-----+---------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|   1 | 2024-07-22 10:00:00 | Dortmund (Lewa)         | FC Porto (Raul)         |           4 |            3 |
|   2 | 2024-07-22 10:00:00 | Barcelona (Prince)      | Arsenal (Carlos)        |           3 |            5 |
|   3 | 2024-07-22 09:45:00 | Barcelona (Prince)      | FC Porto (Raul)         |           1 |            5 |
|   4 | 2024-07-22 09:45:00 | Lazio (Mars)            | Arsenal (Carlos)        |           2 |            5 |

Como puedo calcular una probabilidad (porcentaje) en base a partidos ganados, perdidos o empatados de cada equipo?
En principio si selecciono el total de partidos indicando si han ganado, perdido y empatado (entre el total jugados * 100) lo debería poder calcular, pero la columna MATCHES_TOTAL no la reconoce dando el siguiente error:
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'MATCHES_TOTAL' in 'field list'

La query que trato de usar hasta la fecha es la siguiente:
SELECT
  TEAM,
  count(*) as MATCHES_TOTAL,
  concat(round((WIN / MATCHES_TOTAL * 100), 0), '%') AS WIN_PERCENT,
  concat(round((LOSS / MATCHES_TOTAL * 100), 0), '%') AS LOSS_PERCENT,
  concat(round((DRAW / MATCHES_TOTAL * 100), 0), '%') AS DRAW_PERCENT
FROM
  (SELECT HOME as TEAM, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME > RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WIN, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME = RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DRAW, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME < RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LOSS, RESULT_HOME as RESULT
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT VISIT as TEAM,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT > RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WIN, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT = RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DRAW, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT < RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LOSS, RESULT_VISIT as RESULT
  FROM matches
) as t
GROUP BY TEAM;

Que me está fallando para obtener los datos esperados?

Siguiendo tu lógica de lo que esperas para los porcentajes de victorias, derrotas y empates de un determinado equipo de futbol, la solución sería agregar una suma por cada condición y no usar la columna ya expresada MATCHES_TOTAL en la misma sentencia porque no la puedes nombrar dos veces sino te arroja ese error.
SELECT
  t.TEAM,
  count(*) as MATCHES_TOTAL,
  concat(round((SUM(WIN) / count(*) * 100), 0), '%') AS WIN_PERCENT,
  concat(round((SUM(LOSS) / count(*) * 100), 0), '%') AS LOSS_PERCENT,
  concat(round((SUM(DRAW) / count(*) * 100), 0), '%') AS DRAW_PERCENT
FROM
  (SELECT HOME as TEAM, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME > RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WIN, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME = RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DRAW, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_HOME < RESULT_VISIT THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LOSS, RESULT_HOME as RESULT
  FROM matches
  UNION ALL
  SELECT VISIT as TEAM,
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT > RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as WIN, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT = RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as DRAW, 
    CASE WHEN RESULT_VISIT < RESULT_HOME THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as LOSS, RESULT_VISIT as RESULT
  FROM matches
) as t
GROUP BY TEAM;

Te dejo un demo de como se muestra
